# Replace last instance of comma with 'and' in a string

Tags: java, java-8

I have a string of comma separated words e.g. `"a, b, c"`.
I need to replace the last comma instance with “and”, to make it look like `"a, b and c"`.

I've tried using replaceFirst like this:

```
"a, b, c".replaceFirst("(,)[^,]+$", " and")
```

But it doesn't work. It replaces everything after the last comma with “and” rather than just the comma producing `"a, b and"`.

How to make it work?
I'm on java8.

Ps. I thought that it's obvious, but it seems like I need to clarify, that I'm looking for a generic solution that works with any number of comma separated tokens, i.e. 'a, b, ...., c'

Comment: String's 'lastIndexOf' would help

Comment: i'm also thinking of lastIndexOf but it can't be use on replace right?

Comment: Use `"a, b, c".replaceFirst(",([^,]+)$", " and$1")`

Comment: @Holger haha,we are the same.

Comment: @holi-java: I already noticed. It’s the most straight-forward way to fix the question’s approach, imho.

Comment: @Holger I thought that my answer was wrong ago， until I see your solution are the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the `replaceFirst` is better than `replaceAll` for you because you want to replace only **once** not all, and it run faster than `replaceAll`.

1. using `${number}` to capturing groups.

   ```
   "a, b, c".replaceFirst(",([^,]+)$", " and$1"); // return "a, b and c"
   ```
2. using positive lookahead:

   ```
   "a, b, c".replaceFirst(",(?=[^,]+$)", " and"); // return "a, b and c"
   ```

Comment: I did not down-vote, but that `replaceFirst` is quiet misleading; it's actually a single replace there... May be replacing with `replaceAll` would make more sense.

Comment: @Eugene I think `replaceFirst` better meaniful than `replaceAll`, because OP want to replace **once**. thanks, I want to know why vote it down.

Comment: @Holger I don't care about the votes, I want to know why vote it down? can you tell me why?

Comment: @Holger I have removed it from answer, You may have misunderstood me. I just want to know why ? and learning more from why vote it down.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think you need anything particular from Java 8 here.  If you want to go the regex route with [`String#replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), then you can consider using the following pattern:

```
(.*), (.*)
```

Simple rebuild the string using the first and second capture groups, with `and` in between them.  The first pattern `(.*)` will greedily consume *everything* until the last comma, exactly the behavior you want.  Then, the second `(.*)` does cleanup to capture the final letter/string.

```
String input = "a, b, c";
input = input.replaceAll("(.*), (.*)", "$1 and $2");
System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
a, b and c
```

Comment: You might add why it works: The first `.*` is greedy, so consumes all but the last `,`. (Well, they're both greedy, but the earlier one gets to be greedy first.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve same thing using `lastIndexOf` :

```
String str = "a, b, c";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);
int lastindex = str.lastIndexOf(",");
builder.replace(lastindex, lastindex + 1, " and" );
System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Output:

```
a, b and c
```

Comment: Sometimes, a lightweight `StringBuilder` operation might be preferable to a regex manipulation, but then, it would be more efficient to use partial copying instead of copying the entire string and shifting content: `int lastindex = str.lastIndexOf(',');   String result = new StringBuilder(str.length()+3) .append(str, 0, lastindex).append(" and") .append(str, lastindex+1, str.length()) .toString();`